# How to fix flutter app not launching with fatal exception after upgrading

Tags: flutter, dart

I recently upgraded flutter to 1.2 and on testing it on a real device it ends up crashing.
Here's is the error it throws on the debug console:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(21890): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(21890): Process: com.example.instagram_clone, PID: 21890
E/AndroidRuntime(21890): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.instagram_clone-Z7ozUBGogMCjxOJ-rLwCOQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.instagram_clone-Z7ozUBGogMCjxOJ-rLwCOQ==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:999)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5742)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1680)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.instagram_clone-Z7ozUBGogMCjxOJ-rLwCOQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.instagram_clone-Z7ozUBGogMCjxOJ-rLwCOQ==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:993)
E/AndroidRuntime(21890):    ... 9 more
```

Any help will be appreciated.
I also ran `flutter upgrade` , `flutter pub get` and `flutter clean`.
I am testing the app on a real device and it worked before i upgraded.

Comment: Can you confirm if you have `MainActivity.java` or `MainActivity.kt` with the proper class declaration?

Comment: Yes i have all.

Comment: just make sure the package name on mainactivity.java or mainactivity.kt is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by starting another project and copying lib file,pubspec.yaml and/or assets folder to the new project. Unfotunately i had to reconnect to firebase/or any other backend all over again.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue. The reason I found is that I changed the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml files at Main, debug and profile in Android --> App.

Solved the issue by changing the Package name with the new one in MainActivity.Kt

Answer (score 1):

I changed com.example.myapp to match what I had used to set up firebase under myapp -->
android --> app --> main --> kotlin --> myapp --> MainActivity.kt

Comment: did you changed the folder names ?

Answer (score -1):

me too thats the only way ,
I started brand new project. copied Everything again ...had to do allot of changes. (3 times )
all backend again ,
all manifest build.gradle, podfile, info.plist and ALL that again
however the easiest way a little faster...
of your bundle is : com.domain.coolapp
flutter create coolapp --org com.domain it some other location where the coolapp folder can be created without conflict...for me this happens when the location services (geolocator , location and such ). get funny and just crashes the app like crazy.
also had to do this >adb shell , pm uninstall com.domain.coolapp, exit